# Getting a resized screenshot from a UIView

Tags: iphone, image-processing, ios4, uiimage

I'm trying to take a screenshot of a UIView shrunk down to thumbnail size with the following code,

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    [canvas.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    result = [UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() retain];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

The above code will simply grab the top left portion of the view in the original unshrunk size instead.

I'm sure I've done this before, but I just can't get it working. Anyone know what's off here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Supposing that you have a `CGSize origSize` which is the original size (e.g. 768x1024) and a `CGSize size` which is the required size, this can be done like so:

```
CGFloat scaleX = size.width / origSize.width;
CGFloat scaleY = size.height / origSize.height;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(origSize, NO, scaleX > scaleY ? scaleY : scaleX);
[canvas.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Note that we're using `origSize` in the begun context, not `size`. The scale affects the size as well.

Update (roughly a year later): note that this technique interferes with (or is interefered by) transforms on the `UIView` being snapshotted. If the above is not working and you're doing scale transforms on the view (or its layer), you may wanna go with this solution: [How to scale down a UIImage and make it crispy / sharp at the same time instead of blurry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141298/how-to-scale-down-a-uiimage-and-make-it-crispy-sharp-at-the-same-time-instead)

Comment: +1 Great! UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions is only available on iOS 4.0 and over

Answer (score 0):

I find that this solution generates thumbnails that are the right size.

```
    let thumbRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 512, height: 666)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(thumbSize)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()     
    self.view.frame = thumbRect
    self.view.layer.renderInContext(context)
    thumbImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

However, the resized image adopts the trait collection from the original view controller. 
So although the size is correct, some auto layout features still end-up visible in the resulting image.