# Scale down to fit an image in FOP

Tags: image, pdf, size, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am using FOP version 1.0 to create PDFs. In one of the pages I'd like to display an image (2552 x 4200 pixel) and scale it down if it doesn't fully fit on the page. As far as I could see on the [mailing list](http://old.nabble.com/scale-image-if-too-large-td20487957.html) the recommended way of doing this would be following:

```
<fo:external-graphic inline-progression-dimension.maximum="100%" 
                     content-height="scale-down-to-fit" 
                     content-width="scale-down-to-fit" 
                     src="..."/>
```

Unfortunately, that still doesn't display the whole image. The lower part of the image is cut off. Can anyone give me a hint on what I am potentially doing wrong?

Comment: What is the format of the image?

Comment: In this case it's a TIFF image.

Comment: I included a TIFF image in a small FO file using `fo:external-graphic` exactly as you did, and the output was fine. I could not reproduce the problem. Can you provide some more information (perhaps a link to the image in question)?

Comment: Unfortunately, the image is confidential so I cannot provide you with an image.

Comment: I could make this work by defining the exact height and width of the "viewport": `<fo:external-graphic height="29.7cm" width="21cm" content-height="scale-down-to-fit" content-width="scale-down-to-fit" src="..."/>`. Can anybody explain to me why I apparently have to define that in my case?

Comment: @BenjaminMuschko Did you ever figure out why you had to do this?

Comment: @berry120: No, not really.

Comment: Check if this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141298/how-to-scale-down-a-uiimage-and-make-it-crispy-sharp-at-the-same-time-instead/7775470#7775470

Answer (score 18):

[I found this page here explaining how scaling works with XSL-FO](http://xep.xattic.com/xep/testsuite/usecases/image-scale.pdf).

Essentially, this is the  snippet that I used to make it work:

```
<fo:external-graphic
    src="url('...')"
    width="100%"
    content-height="100%"
    content-width="scale-to-fit"
    scaling="uniform"
    xsl:use-attribute-sets="img"/>
```

I found that `width="100%"` was the missing piece in your own attempts. Hope this helps future visitors.

Comment: `width="100%" content-width="scale-to-fit"` seems to be enough.

Comment: This will grow the image height outside its container even if it has a specified height.

Answer (score 3):

> Defining the exact height and width of the "viewport":
>   .

If you don't specify the viewport then FOP won't know what to scale your image to.

It can guess, but not know precisely.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have access to the project anymore. I'd love to try this out.