# Option for using scale-down-to-fit with a2x and FOP

Tags: apache-fop, asciidoc, a2x

I'm doing a build system for a documentation project and I need help trying to limit the width of images when generating PDF output.

I'm using `a2x --fop` to generate the PDF output which works fine, but I need the `scale-down-to-fit` option ([Scale down to fit an image in FOP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220316/scale-down-to-fit-an-image-in-fop)) enabled for all images.

How can I enable this while using `a2x --fop`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remarkably, I managed to sort this out even though XSL(T) is all smoke and mirrors to me!

To enable this, I managed to get an XSL example from http://www.renderx.com/usecasestest.html and example the XML produced by a2x to craft the following snippet which I've currently added to the default fo.xsl included with asciidoc/a2x:

```
<xsl:template match="imagedata">
    <fo:block line-height="1pt">
        <fo:external-graphic content-width="scale-down-to-fit" content-height="100%" width="100%" scaling="uniform">
            <xsl:attribute name="src">
                url(
                <xsl:value-of select="@fileref"/>
                )
            </xsl:attribute>
        </fo:external-graphic>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```