# UIScrollview changes UIButton's image quality on zoom out

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, image, ios5

I've got a large display area that can be panned and zoomed to view different objects. The problem that I'm running into is that the quality of the PNG images UIButton becomes somewhat degraded if I'm zoomed out (however it is back to normal when I zoom back in to 100%). It almost looks as if the image becomes oversharpened. Is this something that I'm going to have to live with, or is there a way to get rid of this grainy edge effect? The aspect ratio of the images are always 1:1, by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7775470/403952) in my scrollViewDidEndZooming method. Here is my code:

**Resize function**

```
- (UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage*)image newSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    CGRect newRect = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height));
    CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Set the quality level to use when rescaling
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
    CGAffineTransform flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, newSize.height);

    CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipVertical);  
    // Draw into the context; this scales the image
    CGContextDrawImage(context, newRect, imageRef);

    // Get the resized image from the context and a UIImage
    CGImageRef newImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef];

    CGImageRelease(newImageRef);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    

    return newImage;
}
```

**ScrollView Method**
*(Widget is a UIViewController subclass which contains a button and a "widgetImage" which stores the full resolution of the image that the button should display)*

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale
{ 
    for(Widget *theWidget in widgets){
        UIImage *newScaledImage = [self resizeImage:theWidget.widgetImage newSize:CGSizeMake(theWidget.view.frame.size.width * scale, theWidget.view.frame.size.height * scale)];
        [theWidget.widgetButton setImage:newScaledImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        // theWidget.widgetButton.currentImage = newScaledImage;
    }
}
```