# Scale down a UIImage

Tags: ios, uiimage

How does one scale down a UIImage equally on both dimensions by half?

I have a UIImage that is double the size of the UIImageView and would like it to be the same size, without using any of the content modes for filling or scaling etc.

Comment: look this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141298/how-to-scale-down-a-uiimage-and-make-it-crispy-sharp-at-the-same-time-instead

Answer (score 6):

Just make yourself a new image (expressed as a category method of UIImage) :

```
- (UIImage*)scaleToSize:(CGSize)size {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, size.width, size.height), self.CGImage);

    UIImage* scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return scaledImage;
}
```