# Capturing image at higher resolution in iOS

Tags: ios, camera, avfoundation

Currently i am working on an image app where i am able to capture an image by using AVFoundation framework. But what i am looking is , to capture an image with certain resolution and DPI (may be 300 DPI or greater).

How to do this ?

Comment: DPI is print resolution, not capture, unless you're talking about a scanner. Are you capturing the screen or camera?

Comment: i want to capture images from iOS camera at higher resolution as after that i will process that image to extract character by using any OCR engine.

Answer (score 2):

There have been numerous posts on here about trying to do OCR on camera generated images. The problem is not that the resolution is too low, but that its too high. I cannot find a link right now, but there was a question a year or so ago where in the end, if the image size was reduced by a factor of four or so, the OCR engine worked better. If you examine the image in Preview, what you want is the number of pixels per character to be say 16x16 or 32x32, not 256x256. Frankly I don't know the exact number but I'm sure you can research this and find posts from actual framework users telling you the best size.

[Here is a nice response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7775470/1633251) on how to best scale a large image (with a link to code).

Comment: Thanks David for feedback but does scaling is the solution ? as i read it some place, just making an image larger by adding extra pixels in between your captured ones or by stretching pixels, but these approaches always just result in an approximation. Your image always loses some clarity and quality !

Comment: The issue as I stated is that the OCR engines expect the text to be in a range of size - they get totally confused when there are an excess of pixels. I cannot think of the name of the common OCR engine, but if you search for posts of that along with the iOS tag, you will find an earlier post by someone have no luck at all with full size images, but good luck after downsizing the image (I had a comment or an answer to that). I suppose the OCR engine is expecting the characters to be sized in some range. You are going to have to research this, or find a subject matter expert (I am not).