# UIImageView resizes automatically

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying to set an image to a `UIImageView` of a `SimpleTableCell` in a `UITableView`. I have changed the size of the imageview, but whenever I try to set the image, it automatically resizes itself. I tried using the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7775470/1082181) to resize the image and set it. But it only works when I set the image dimensions to (20x20) which is half of the size of the `UIImageView` (40x40). So it comes out blurred. I also tried setting `UIAspectRatioFit/UIAspectratioFill` and `clipsToBounds = YES`. Nothing seems to work.

Another strange part is that the `imageView` doesn't resize itself when I use an image directly downloaded from the web like so:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    UIImage *userImage = [UIImage imageWithData:userImageData scale:self.profileImage.frame.size.height/self.profileImage.frame.size.width];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.myTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];

    cell.imageView.image = userImage;
}
```

But then I store this image into a documents directory and then try to reload in elsewhere, the resizing occurs. Any solutions?

Comment: your SimpleTableCell is a subClass of UITableViewCell that you created? This imageView is a property of this subclass?

Comment: have you try set the UIViewAutoResizeMask to None?

Comment: Yes I tried setting UIVIewAutoResizeMask to none and the contentMode to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your SimpleTableCell is a subClass of `UITableViewCell` that you created? This imageView is a property of this subclass?

Just a guess:

Every UITableViewCell has a built-in imageView read-only property. In the code that you posted, you are using this default property, which I believe cannot have it's frame modified, it's kind of fixed in the left side of the cell.

Look for imageView property inside the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/imageView

So, if you do have your custom cell with your own imageView, make sure to not call it `imageView` too, because you may end using the default `UITableViewCell`'s property, and not your own, which will have all your frame customizations and etc.

You should reference your cell by your customClass and call your property like this:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    UIImage *userImage = [UIImage imageWithData:userImageData scale:self.profileImage.frame.size.height/self.profileImage.frame.size.width];

    SimpleTableCell *cell = (SimpleTableCell*)[self.myTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];

    cell.myImageView.image = userImage;
}
```

Don't know if the problem is really related do this, so let me know if it helped or not.

Comment: The cell I'm using is the default UITableViewCell provided in iOS. It's not custom.

Comment: So, like I said, it's not a good practice to edit this default read-only properties. You should consider to create a custom cell of yours, with a imageView inside it, where you could freely edit it's properties, like frame, contentMode etc.

Comment: Yea I ended up doing that, though I was trying really hard to avoid it. But thanks for your answer. :)

Comment: Your answer saved my life

Comment: wow , didn't know that by default UITableViewCell has an imageView property even if its made custom, thanks for info, saved a lot of frustration.

Answer (score 1):

When weird resizing behavior happens for me, Autolayout is my first suspect. Try turning Autolayout off and see if the resizing still occurs.

1. Select the ViewController in the Storyboard or NIB
2. Click the 'File Inspector' tab on the right hand side of your Xcode window
3. Under the 'Interface Builder Document' section, uncheck 'Use Autolayout'

If you need Autolayout you'll probably have to battle it with some code.

Comment: Agree, but also check the imageview contentMode.  Make sure that it's one of the "*Fit" modes.

Comment: I am not using a custom cell. I just wanna use the default UITableViewCell and change the frames accordingly.