# How do I programmatically change an image in an existing UIImageView and make it fit inside the image view's constraints?

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, interface-builder, autolayout

I have a UIImageView and when I set an image in that view using IB, the image is the correct size when I run the app (40x40). When I programmatically change the image using the code below, the new image is 400x400 or so. This is using the same image that I know works fine if it's set in IB. Do I have to scale the image before I add it to the UIImageView? I assumed auto-layout's constraints would automatically do this for me.

```
UIImage *messageTypeImage = [UIImage imageNamed:message.imageName];
[messageCell.imageView setImage:messageTypeImage];
[messageCell.contentView layoutIfNeeded];
```

The UIImageView's content mode is set to "Scale To Fill" and I've tried adding the code below both before and after calling setImage:

```
[messageCell.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];
[messageCell.imageView setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

Here's how the constraints are set up for the image view:

[image]

Comment: You might try `[messageCell layoutIfNeeded];`.

Comment: Jessamaphone, thanks for the suggestion but I'm already calling [messageCell.contentView layoutIfNeeded]; I've updated the question to reflect that.

Comment: What is you view Mode (i.e. contentMode) value?  Scale to Fill?

Comment: Which constraints do you have set on the imageView in IB?  Do you have width and height constraints?  Or do you have constraints on all four sides of the imageView?

Comment: So, your image is showing up on screen as larger than 40x40?

Comment: vacawama, yes, the image shows as its native size, it's not scaled to fit at all. The same image looks fine (40x40) if I set it in IB and not programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using iOS 8 SDK? If so, try overriding layoutSubviews in your cell subclass and add this:

```
   self.contentView.frame = self.bounds;
   self.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

There are some problems with the contentViews' of collection view/table view cells constraints/masks.

Answer (score 0):

Wow. Finally found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18129840/26535). Turns out, there's a default imageView outlet in prototype cells. I was unknowingly using that outlet and not the UIImageView I thought I was using.