# How to resize an image and avoid it being blurry?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I am currently using code that is not blurry but it just cuts a piece out, and if I try to use different ones online, it cuts a piece out and it becomes blurry as well. What do I need to be doing, the picture is 512x512 trying to get it down to 100x100 and it is a jpg.

Here is the code I use now:

```
//setting up each cell
    -(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                     cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        CollectionGridCell *myCell = [collectionView
                                        dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"GridCell"
                                        forIndexPath:indexPath];


        long row = [indexPath row];

           NSURL *baseUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/"];

    NSString *imageItemName = [homeImages objectAtIndex:row];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:imageItemName relativeToURL:baseUrl];

   // NSURL *url = /* prepare a url... see note below */
    [myCell.homeImage setImageWithURL:url
                     placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menuButton.png"]
                            completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
                                // inspect cacheType here to make sure it's cached as you want it
                               myCell.homeImage.image = [self resizeImage:image newSize:CGSizeMake(75,75)];

                            }];

    return myCell;

}


- (UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage*)image newSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    CGRect newRect = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height));
    CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Set the quality level to use when rescaling
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
    CGAffineTransform flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, newSize.height);

    CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipVertical);
    // Draw into the context; this scales the image
    CGContextDrawImage(context, newRect, imageRef);

    // Get the resized image from the context and a UIImage
    CGImageRef newImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef];

    CGImageRelease(newImageRef);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;

}
```

UPDATE: Every method I tried even the ones below so far, lead to a cropping out of the middle. Do I have to specify something else in my code, is there something calling it to crop out the middle?

This is my grid cell .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CollectionGridCell : UICollectionViewCell
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *homeImage;

@end
```

This is my grid cell .m file:

```
#import "CollectionGridCell.h"

@implementation CollectionGridCell

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to re-size the image. Just set below property to your image view.

```
 [myCell.homeImage setImageWithURL:url
                     placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menuButton.png"]
                            completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {
                                // inspect cacheType here to make sure it's cached as you want it
                               myCell.homeImage.image = image;
                               myCell.homeImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
                            }];
```

Comment: Where would I include this right where I call the resize method, because doing that does not seem to scale the image down? How would I specify if I want it 100x 100 or 50x50 i.e.

Comment: There is no need to call re-size function. See the updated answer. Image will be fit automatically in ImageView.

Comment: Ok but doing this method it seems to just crop out the middle of the image and does not show the whole image just smaller...

Comment: Is there something in my code maybe that I need to change since all these methods always seem to crop the middle out?

Comment: Provide proper frame to myCell.homeImage.frame. Also, share the code for myCell class.

Comment: Ok I added the cell class, what do you mean by proper frame, what should I be adding for that?

Comment: cell.homeImage.frame = CGRectMake(x_origin, y_origin, 100,100);

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a Simple solution:**

```
- (UIImage *)resizeImage:(UIImage*)image newSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    CGRect newRect = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height));
    CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Set the quality level to use when rescaling
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh);
    CGAffineTransform flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, newSize.height);

    CGContextConcatCTM(context, flipVertical);  
    // Draw into the context; this scales the image
    CGContextDrawImage(context, newRect, imageRef);

    // Get the resized image from the context and a UIImage
    CGImageRef newImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef];

    CGImageRelease(newImageRef);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    

    return newImage;
}
```

**Referred from this Link:-**

http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/.

[How to scale down a UIImage and make it crispy / sharp at the same time instead of blurry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141298/how-to-scale-down-a-uiimage-and-make-it-crispy-sharp-at-the-same-time-instead)

Answer (score 0):

Method :

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,0,100,100);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size );
[yourCurrentOriginalImage drawInRect:rect];
UIImage *picture1 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(picture1);
UIImage *img=[UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Method 2:

```
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)]; //image => Your imageName
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

**ImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;**

Comment: Trying this does not scale the image and just cuts out a piece of it, so I only see a 100x100 piece of the whole image

Comment: Still the same issue but look at my UPDATE not sure if at this point it is something else that needs to be fixed in my code