# Resize Image without losing quality

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using the functions below to resize my images width & height but I noticed that it ruins the image quality.

```
class func imageWithSize(image: UIImage,size: CGSize)->UIImage{
    if UIScreen.mainScreen().respondsToSelector("scale"){
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size,false,UIScreen.mainScreen().scale);
    }
    else
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    }

    image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height));
    var newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}

class func resizeImageWithAspect(image: UIImage,scaledToMaxWidth width:CGFloat,maxHeight height :CGFloat)->UIImage
{


    let scaleFactor =  width / height;


    let newSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);

    return imageWithSize(image, size: newSize);
}
```

Is there another way to resize images without ruining the quality? Or how can I fix my functions below so it doesn't ruin the image quality after resizing?

Comment: Which quality do you get, and which quality do you expect?

Comment: @Mats It resizes the images correctly to whatever width and height I pass to the function.  The problem is that the image becomes blurry

Comment: FYI - the `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` function was added in iOS 4. Checking to see if you should use it or not in this day and age is pointless.

Comment: @rmaddy any idea on what I should use for iOS 8?  I just want to resize the height and width without having the output become blurry

Comment: What you are doing looks correct as long as the newSize maintains the original aspect ratio and you are making the image smaller.

Answer (score 51):

Here is my code in swift. For squared images, it works really well and without any loss of quality!

```
extension UIImage {

    func resize(targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:targetSize).image { _ in
            self.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize))
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for iOS 10.0 and above.

Comment: It's unbelievable that this isn't the answer that's everywhere. Nearly every answer out there is long, convoluted, and distorts the image, but this doesn't.

Comment: It works for squared image but what about other images which are not squared ?

Comment: Thanks, you are safe me

Comment: Perfect! So much cleaner than the others. Of course, I'm working exclusively with square pics. But I expect if the aspect ratio is the same it should work for rectangular ones as well...

Comment: All above answers decrease the quality. Only this answer kept the video quality.

Comment: Thank you for saving my time. This solution worked on first attempt.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my `Objective-C` code. It's work for me.

```
+ (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize isAspectRation:(BOOL)aspect {
    if (!image) {
        return nil;
    }
    //UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    // In next line, pass 0.0 to use the current device's pixel scaling factor (and thus account for Retina resolution).
    // Pass 1.0 to force exact pixel size.
    CGFloat originRatio = image.size.width / image.size.height;
    CGFloat newRatio = newSize.width / newSize.height;

    CGSize sz;

    if (!aspect) {
        sz = newSize;
    }else {
        if (originRatio < newRatio) {
            sz.height = newSize.height;
            sz.width = newSize.height * originRatio;
        }else {
            sz.width = newSize.width;
            sz.height = newSize.width / originRatio;
        }
    }
    CGFloat scale = 1.0;
    //    if([[UIScreen mainScreen]respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]) {
    //        CGFloat tmp = [[UIScreen mainScreen]scale];
    //        if (tmp > 1.5) {
    //            scale = 2.0;
    //        }
    //    }
    sz.width /= scale;
    sz.height /= scale;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(sz, NO, scale);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, sz.width, sz.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

I saw your code in `Swift`. I just convert my `Objective-C` to `Swift` without test. Can you try it and let's me know. Thanks!

```
struct CommonUtils {
    static func imageWithImage(image: UIImage, scaleToSize newSize: CGSize, isAspectRation aspect: Bool) -> UIImage{

        let originRatio = image.size.width / image.size.height;//CGFloat
        let newRatio = newSize.width / newSize.height;

        var sz: CGSize = CGSizeZero

        if (!aspect) {
            sz = newSize
        }else {
            if (originRatio < newRatio) {
                sz.height = newSize.height
                sz.width = newSize.height * originRatio
            }else {
                sz.width = newSize.width
                sz.height = newSize.width / originRatio
            }
        }
        let scale: CGFloat = 1.0

        sz.width /= scale
        sz.height /= scale
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(sz, false, scale)
        image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, sz.width, sz.height))
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I just created this useful UIImage extension with swift 5. You can use it to resize your UIImages without losing quality.

I added a couple of methods in order to be able to resize an image to a width or a height keeping the aspect ratio.

```swift
extension UIImage {

    func resize(targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:targetSize).image { _ in
            self.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize))
        }
    }

    func resize(scaledToWidth desiredWidth: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        let oldWidth = size.width
        let scaleFactor = desiredWidth / oldWidth

        let newHeight = size.height * scaleFactor
        let newWidth = oldWidth * scaleFactor
        let newSize = CGSize(width: newWidth, height: newHeight)

        return resize(targetSize: newSize)
    }

    func resize(scaledToHeight desiredHeight: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
        let scaleFactor = desiredHeight / size.height
        let newWidth = size.width * scaleFactor
        let newSize = CGSize(width: newWidth, height: desiredHeight)

        return resize(targetSize: newSize)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
func image(image:UIImage,imageSize:CGSize)->UIImage
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, false, 0.0)
    [image .drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 3, imageSize.width, imageSize.height))]
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage;
}
```

Comment: Consider adding some context / explanation of the main points, so that your answer can be more helpful.

Comment: - Decrease the video quality. Henry's Answer is good.