# Scale down image without losing quality in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, image-scaling

In my app, due to payload error when sending image from ios app to watch app, I am scaling my image so that it fits into watch, but the quality on watch is blurry. How can i scale it without losing quality.

source code done so far is:

```
    var holding_Image: UIImage?
@IBOutlet weak var display_image: UIImageView!
 imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(holding_Image!)!
let img = UIImage(data: self.imageData)

let imgsize = CGSize(width: 100.0, height: 100.0)
let newimg = imageget.imageResize(img, andResizeTo: imgsize)

let newdata = UIImagePNGRepresentation(newimg!)

 self.dic1.setObject(newdata!, forKey: "image_data")
```

Comment: Have you checked the width and height of the original image?

Comment: manage aspect ratio

Comment: Have you already tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612760/resize-image-without-losing-quality

Comment: actually i am cropping image from original image and then sending cropped image to watch . The image view in my storyboard which holds the cropped image is 144*122 size and  my original cropped image size is 220*220

Comment: hey pedrouan.. the link you have given, but how do i apply it in my code?