UITabbar item image Downloaded from server shows blur but if use same image from assets folder it works fine
I have created UITabbar for my app and as per the requirements all the information will come from the API. Once I received the response I have downloaded the image and set to UITabbar Item.
I have used the following code to download the image.
for (int i=0; i<[tabbarItemImageArray count]; i++) {

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    [[session dataTaskWithURL:[tabbarItemImageArray objectAtIndex:i]
              completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                  NSURLResponse *response,
                                  NSError *error) {
        
        UIImage *imagemain=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
        
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){
            
            if (i < 5) {
                
                if (imagemain != nil) {


                    UIImage *resizedImage = [[WSUtils sharedObject] resizeImageForTabbarItem:imagemain scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(25,25)];

                    self.tabBarController.tabBar.items[i].image = [resizedImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
               self.tabBarController.tabBar.items[i].selectedImage = resizedImage;
                }
                
                self.tabBarController.tabBar.items[i].title = [tabbarItemNameArray objectAtIndex:i];
                self.tabBarController.tabBar.unselectedItemTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:35/255.0 green:63/255.0 blue:136/255.0 alpha:1.0];
            }
            
        });

      }] resume];

tabbarItemImageArray is Array of NSURL object which contains the image url. I have created UITabbarController programmatically. These are the properties I have used.
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
self.tabBarController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = tabbarArray;
self.tabBarController.tabBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.tabBarController.tabBar.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
self.tabBarController.tabBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 0.0);
self.tabBarController.tabBar.layer.shadowRadius = 5;
self.tabBarController.tabBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3;
self.tabBarController.tabBar.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
self.tabBarController.tabBar.layer.cornerRadius = 30;
self.tabBarController.tabBar.backgroundImage = [[UIImage alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.tabBar.layer.maskedCorners = kCALayerMinXMinYCorner | kCALayerMaxXMinYCorner;
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;

This will give following result. See Highlight UITabbar in Red color.

If I download an image and add it to the image assets in Xcode and Run the app it shows clean image. See below image.

I have spent full day on this and nothing has found. Any help will appreaciated even if it is in a swift.
Updated:
I have tried 25x25, 50x50 and 75x75 image. I have uploaded one by one all 3 size of image and tried but it is not working. I am attaching example icon of 50x50 image. which I have used for above screen shots.

I have resized 50x50 image to 25x25 for tabbar items, as 50x50 is too big to fit in Tabbar. Following method I have used to do resize.
-(UIImage*) resizeImageForTabbarItem:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {

float width = newSize.width;
    float height = newSize.height;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);

    float widthRatio = image.size.width / width;
    float heightRatio = image.size.height / height;
    float divisor = widthRatio > heightRatio ? widthRatio : heightRatio;

    width = image.size.width / divisor;
    height = image.size.height / divisor;

    rect.size.width  = width;
    rect.size.height = height;

    //indent in case of width or height difference
    float offset = (width - height) / 2;
    if (offset > 0) {
        rect.origin.y = offset;
    }
    else {
        rect.origin.x = -offset;
    }

    [image drawInRect: rect];

    UIImage *smallImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return smallImage;

}

What size is the blurry image? Maybe it's a tiny image and it's blurry because it's being scaled bigger.

I’d recommend sharing, for one of the tabs, (a) the asset from the assets library; and (b) the corresponding asset downloaded by the data task (e.g., write the Data received to a file). But, in short, see HIG – Tab bars – Target dimensions for recommended asset dimensions. Your images look like they are some smaller size that has been scaled to fit the UI.

@HangarRash  Thank you for your consideration. I have edited the question you can find the image in question. I have used 5 different sizes 25x25, 50x50, 75x75, 100x100, 150x150. As any image which has size greater then 25x25 not fit in Tabbar and go out of the tabbar so I have resized them. I am using bigger image and try to scal smaller but result is same.

@Rob Thank you for your consideration. I have added an image in question which I have downloaded from API url. I have used same image in assets folder. I have added 50x50 image in 1x, 2x and 3x for testing purpose and run the app. It gives clear icon as you can see attached above screen shot no 2. As you mentioned I have used 50x50 and 75x75 and resize them to smaller size like 25x25 but result is same.

I have found the solution. Resize the image actually causing the issue. If you used following method it will resize the image with maintaining image quality.
Swift 5.0
extension UIImage {

func resize(targetSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:targetSize).image { _ in
        self.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: targetSize))
    }
}

}
Objective C:
-(UIImage*) resizeImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {

UIGraphicsImageRenderer *renderer = [[UIGraphicsImageRenderer alloc] initWithSize:newSize];

UIImage *resizedImage = [renderer imageWithActions:^(UIGraphicsImageRendererContext * _Nonnull context) {
    
    CGPoint point = CGPointZero;
    CGRect aRect = { point, newSize };
    
    [image drawInRect:aRect];
    
  }];

return resizedImage;

}
I have found the answer from the following link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49060676/2384760
