# Swift setting image as button, clicking too hard

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, swift2, ios9

I've set a `transparent image` as the `background` for a `UIButton` I'm using. It looks perfect, but the problem is the `transparent image` is fairly small, so it's not easy for users to click it correctly on their first try.

---

Here's my code:

```
optionsButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "CalendarEventArrowIcon"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
optionsButton.addTarget(self, action: "optionsButtonPressed", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
```

---

Is there a way that I can take the current image I'm using, and place it inside a UIImage with a larger frame, and then make that the background image for the button `programmatically` in  `Swift`?

By doing this, it would make it easier for a user to click the button since the background image would take up a larger area.

Or is the only way for me to actually to do something like this to go back into Photoshop and make the `background image` I'm using larger and no longer have a `transparent background`?

Comment: hm ... i suggest you to do the Photoshop job again to make the picture large enough.

Comment: The easiest way is to make the the image larger, or embed the button inside of a clear UIView and add a tap gesture recognizer to it which triggers the optionsButtonPressed action.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can extend the tappable area of the button using `contentEdgeInsets`. For example, to add 15 points of padding around the button on all sides, add the following:

`optionsButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(15, 15, 15, 15)`

Answer (score 1):

So bottom line you want to resize image programmatically in swift.
See if this helps (votes 12 and comments say it works) :

[swift resize image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31966885/ios-swift-resize-image-to-200x200pt-px)

Answer (score 0):

```
optionsButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "CalendarEventArrowIcon"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)

optionsButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector("optionsButtonPressed"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
```

Comment: all you did was take my code and add the `Selector` tag to the action parameter. Swift 2 doesn't need the `Selector` tag so this does nothing