# iOS app taking too long to fetch result from PHP webserver

Tags: php, ios, swift, web-services, nsurlsession

Using an iOS app, I am trying to trigger an image processing script, built using PHP, on the webserver i.e. Macbook in this case. When I manually run the script on
Macbook, it hardly takes around 1 minute to deliver the result. But when it is triggered from the app using NSURLSessionConfiguration, it takes a long time approx 7 to 8 mins, but still doesn't return the correct result. Any idea why this task performed using the app takes so long than it does when run manually?

I have changed these session parameters, but didn't see any fruitful result. Please guide me.

1. sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 500.0;
2. sessionConfig.timeoutIntervalForResource = 500.0;

Additional information:
The PHP script called by the iOS app has two functions. The first function takes less time to run both manually and also when triggered through app. If the workflow is limited until this function, I am able to see the appropriate result on the app screen. The problem stated above in this thread lies only with the second function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reduced the image size in the app before posting it to the webserver. This measure drastically improved the speed with which the correct result is shown on the app screen. Earlier it took around 8 mins and still would not work. Now, it returns the result in less than 3 seconds.

Check this link for reducing image size
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31984155/3681985

Answer (score 0):

If possible separate the function into two request. You may try https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire for web service call.

Comment: Thanks Mohan. I didn't try your suggestion yet. Started with reducing image size and that worked well.