# CGRectMake, CGPointMake, CGSizeMake, CGRectZero, CGPointZero is unavailable in Swift

Tags: uikit, swift3, xcode8, ios10

After converting code to latest swift 3.0 I am shown this error.

[image][image]

Also tell me solution for `CGSize = CGSizeMake(0,0)`

```
static var frameAtStartOfPan: CGRect = CGRectZero
static var startPointOfPan: CGPoint = CGPointZero
```

Which is also unavailable.

Comment: But after converting my previous code to swift3 i got this issue, would like to know if there is any change in syntax in updated version

Answer (score 507, accepted):

`CGRect` Can be simply created using an instance of a `CGPoint` or `CGSize`, thats given below.

```
let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0,y :0), size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))  

// Or

let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
```

Or if we want to specify each value in `CGFloat` or `Double` or `Int`, we can use this method.

```
let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100) // CGFloat, Double, Int
```

`CGPoint` Can be created like this.

```
 let point = CGPoint(x: 0,y :0) // CGFloat, Double, Int
```

`CGSize` Can be created like this.

```
let size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 100) // CGFloat, Double, Int
```

Also size and point with 0 as the values, it can be done like this.

```
let size = CGSize.zero // width = 0, height = 0
let point = CGPoint.zero // x = 0, y = 0, equal to CGPointZero
let rect = CGRect.zero // equal to CGRectZero
```

`CGRectZero` & `CGPointZero` replaced with `CGRect.zero` & `CGPoint.zero` in `Swift 3.0`.

Comment: Can you also tell me solution for CGSize = CGSizeMake(0,0) which is not woking in swift 3

Comment: @niravdesai21 Updated the question, please check.

Comment: CGPointZero and CGRectZero is also not available any solution for that?

Updated Question please update answer

Comment: @niravdesai21 Updated.

Comment: @niravdesai21 I still wonder why didn't you accept anyone of the answer? You need more clarification on this simple matter?

Comment: "CGRectZero is unavailable in Swift" when actually it's a syntax change to CGRect.zero is a joke! These guys need to work on their compile warnings big time... They rely on Stack Overflow to bail them out constantly

Comment: In your first example, you can use shorthand like this: `let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))`

Answer (score 51):

Quick fix for **CGRectMake , CGPointMake, CGSizeMake** in **Swift3 & iOS10**

Add these extensions :

```
extension CGRect{
    init(_ x:CGFloat,_ y:CGFloat,_ width:CGFloat,_ height:CGFloat) {
        self.init(x:x,y:y,width:width,height:height)
    }

}
extension CGSize{
    init(_ width:CGFloat,_ height:CGFloat) {
        self.init(width:width,height:height)
    }
}
extension CGPoint{
    init(_ x:CGFloat,_ y:CGFloat) {
        self.init(x:x,y:y)
    }
}
```

Then go to "**Find and Replace in Workspace**" 
Find *CGRectMake , CGPointMake, CGSizeMake* and Replace them with *CGRect , CGPoint, CGSize*

These steps might save all the time as Xcode right now doesn't give us quick conversion from **Swift 2+** to **Swift 3**

Comment: Brilliant solution!

Comment: @Oprimus hope it reduces your hassle :)

Answer (score 28):

In Swift 3, you can simply use `CGPoint.zero` or `CGRect.zero` in place of `CGRectZero` or `CGPointZero`.

However, in Swift 4, `CGRect.zero` and `'CGPoint.zero'` will work

Answer (score 13):

If you want to use them as in swift 2, you can use these funcs:

For CGRectMake:

```
func CGRectMake(_ x: CGFloat, _ y: CGFloat, _ width: CGFloat, _ height: CGFloat) -> CGRect {
    return CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
}
```

For CGPointMake:

```
func CGPointMake(_ x: CGFloat, _ y: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
}
```

For CGSizeMake:

```
func CGSizeMake(_ width: CGFloat, _ height: CGFloat) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}
```

Just put them outside any class and it should work. (Works for me at least)

Answer (score 9):

The structures as well as all other symbols in Core Graphics and other APIs have become cleaner and also include parameter names. 
https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics#symbols

```
CGRect(x: Int, y: Int, width: Int, height: Int)
CGVector(dx: Int, dy: Int)
CGPoint(x: Double, y: Double)
CGSize(width: Int, height: Int)
```

CGPoint Example:

```
let newPoint = stackMid.convert(CGPoint(x: -10, y: 10), to: self)
```

CGVector Example:

```
self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: gravity)
```

CGSize Example:

```
hero.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: 16, height: 18))
```

CGRect Example:

```
let back = SKShapeNode(rect: CGRect(x: 0-120, y: 1024-200-30, width: 240, height: 140), cornerRadius: 20)
```

**Apple Blog**

Swift syntax and API renaming changes in Swift 3 make the language feel more natural, and provide an even more Swift-y experience when calling Cocoa frameworks. Popular frameworks Core Graphics and Grand Central Dispatch have new, much cleaner interfaces in Swift.

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 3 Bonus:** Why didn't anyone mention the short form?

```
CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
```

**`.zero`** instead of **`CGPoint.zero`**

When the type is defined, you can safely omit it.

Answer (score 5):

Try the following:

```
var myToolBar = UIToolbar.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 44))
```

This is for the *swift's* latest version

Comment: like it (Y), this would be easier for auto completion

Answer (score 4):

You can use this with replacement of CGRectZero

```
CGRect.zero
```

Answer (score 2):

For CGSize

```
CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width * 3, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of CGSizeMake add **CGSize** it will work.
CGSizeMake is used in objective c.

you don't want to use  *make* with swift

Answer (score 1):

**In Swift 4** it works like below

```
collectionView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)
```