# CGSizeMake not available

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I get an error when I want to use CGSizeMake in the latest Xcode. It says that CGSizeMake is not available in Swift anymore. How can I fix this error properly?

```
var V1 : View1 = View1(nibName: "View1", bundle: nil)

var V2 : View2 = View2(nibName: "View2", bundle: nil)


self.addChildViewController(V1)
self.scrollView.addSubview(V1.view)
V1.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

self.addChildViewController(V2)
self.scrollView.addSubview(V2.view)
V1.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

var V2Frame : CGRect = V2.view.frame
V2Frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.width
V2.view.frame = V2Frame

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width * 2, self.view.frame.size.height)
```

Comment: This answer should answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/37948158/5222077

Comment: and how do I fill this in to my code? Tried some varieties but doesn't work yet.

Comment: try `self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width * 2, height: self.view.frame.size.height)`

Comment: yeah that works thank you man!!