# What happened to CGRectGetMidX() and CGRectGetMidY()?

Tags: swift, core-graphics, swift3, cgrect

I'm following a SpriteKit tutorial video from Rob Percival, and this line of code does not compile. It seems the syntax is out of date for getting the "mid x" and "mid y" values. What are the replacements for `CGRectGetMidX()` and `CGRectGetMidY()`?

```
CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is CGRectGetMidX/Y in Swift 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40035825/where-is-cgrectgetmidx-y-in-swift-3)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The syntax for just about everything changed with Swift 3.

You want:

```
man.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
```

See the documentation for `CGRect` for more details.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks so much! I suppose I'll be studying from scratch haha :P