# How to design UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift

How to design UI button like this in iOS? I not understand how to design this:

[image]

Comment: How do we run a search here?

Comment: have a look at this as this is doing the rounded corners. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37164262/3483812

Comment: literally take that image, and dump it as the image for the button, done

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not very difficult and the the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37946990/cgrectmake-cgpointmake-cgsizemake-cgrectzero-cgpointzero-is-unavailable-in-s) should suffices the requirement with some modification nevertheless, I have created a button like you want. Please check the code from [GitHub](https://github.com/jeetendra-choudhary/UIBtnProject.git)

Basically you can create an extension for the button and provide the desired properties there like rounded corner and specify the corner radius as per your requirement also which corner you want the radius to be applied i.e in your case top left and right bottom.

```
extension UIButton{
    func roundedButton(){
        let maskPAth1 = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,
                                 byRoundingCorners: [.topLeft , .bottomRight],
                                 cornerRadii:CGSize(width:20.0, height:20.0))
        let maskLayer1 = CAShapeLayer()
        maskLayer1.frame = self.bounds
        maskLayer1.path = maskPAth1.cgPath
        self.layer.mask = maskLayer1

    }
}
```

This would give you a button like -

[image]

You can customise the text and colour of text as per your need.

That should be enough irrespective of number of custom buttons you want. Going with image and storyboard customisation would need rework for every button, hence I recommend this approach. Cleaner and better.

Comment: It shows extra arguments 'byRounding corners' in call.Why it is shows?

Comment: Where exactly it shows that?

Comment: In this line there is showing error------     
        let maskPAth1 = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds,
            byRoundingCorners: [.top , .bottomRight],
            cornerRadii:CGSize(width:20.0, height:20.0))

Comment: Please check the version of xCode you are using because it doesn't show any error at my end.

Comment: Version 6.0.1 (6A317)

Comment: You are using way too old version pal, please upgrade to xCode 8 at least.

Comment: without xcode  updating my code is working

Answer (score 3):

The easiest thing to do is to create a custom button with an image and just put those colored blobs in as the image for each button. Then add a title and adjust the color and font as needed. You can also create a mask layer as desired in the link provided by @Jetpack, although you may need to update the mask layer in a `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` method in your view controller.

Comment: Using images is not the easiest thing to do. It's actually the more difficult way.

Comment: @rmaddy, why do you say that? I've always found it easy.

Comment: See the other answer. Simple code. Easy to change as needed. With images you need to create each image with the proper color and all of the proper sizes. If you want to tweak it you need to edit all of the images. It's a pain. And it makes your app bigger having more images.

Comment: Ok, I see your point. In terms of the button code, the image approach is simpler, but you have a point about the pain of creating and maintaining images. I tend to prefer the code approach, but beginning developers might be intimidated by creating custom button classes.