# What is an alternative for CGSizeMake in Swift 3.0

Tags: swift

I had a bug when I updated to Swift 3.0. For some reason Swift 3.0 doesn't support `CGSizeMake`. My code looks like this:

```
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width*2, 
self.view.frame.size.height)
```

What could be some alternatives for `CGSizeMake` in my case? Please help!

Comment: just use `CGSize(widht: ,height:)`

Comment: [CGSize](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgsize) has `init(width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat)`, etc.

Comment: You can find [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37946990/6541007) searching with "What is an alternative for CGSizeMake in Swift 3.0".

Comment: Put “CGSize” into google. The first result is the documentation. It gives all possible way to initialise CGSize and everything else you can do with it. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgsize Always check the docs.

Comment: @Fogmeister In Xcode shorter and faster: Press ⇧⌘0 and type `CGSize`

Comment: @vadian ah! I use Dash so didn’t know about that one. Will have to give that a go myself. :-)

Comment: Another hint if you are using Xcode:  Just type `CGSize(` and Xcode will show you the available choices.  Double click on one of the ones with `width:` and `height:` and then type in the width value and then <TAB> and type in the height value.  Try it.  It is very useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use

```
CGSize(width: <CGFloat>, height: <CGFloat>)
```

Comment: Very clear comparing to the linked question and answer. Thank you!