# Scale an Image in ImageView (Scale x,y) - IOS

Tags: ios, imageview, scale

I usually scale the image of an imageView in Android with the scaleX and scaleY properties.

How can I do the same in IOS? I'm really new with IOS,I'm using swift 3 and I didn't find any analog thing like that.

Comment: This link may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31966885/ios-swift-resize-image-to-200x200pt-px

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to scale the image proportionally, the following code might work for you:

```
if let cgImage = imageView.image?.cgImage, let orientation = imageView.image?.imageOrientation {
    imageView.image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: newScale, orientation: orientation)
}
```

However, if you only want to display it with a size different than that of the original image, you should control the size of the image using the size of the `UIImageView` that presents it. To make sure the image scales correctly with the size of the view, take a look at the `UIImageView.contentMode` property: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622619-contentmode

Comment: I tried your code but doesn't change anything, i just changed: newScale with 0.5

Comment: Is `contentMode` set to `Scale to Fill`? If so, the `UIImage` might be rescaled back to fill the `UIImageView`. As I said, it is the size of the `UIImageView` that drives the scale of the presented `UIImage`, not the other way around (unless you choose a `contentMode` that does not cause image resizing, such as `center`).

Comment: What constraints have you defined on your `UIImageView`?

Comment: I changed contentMode and now work fine! This is the solution I was looking for but how can I scale only the Y or only the X? Is possible?

Comment: It's possible but much more complicated. Do you need the scaled `UIImage` for any other purpose than displaying it? If not, do you know the expected size of the image beforehand?

Comment: I know the size of the image beforehand and I want to resize it for a better looking purpose. But if is too complicated I think I'd do better to do it with photoshop...

Comment: If you know it beforehand, just add a width and a height constraint to `UIImageView` (to match the desired width and height of the image) and set `contentMode` back to `Scale to Fill`