# How to make two UIImage sizes the same in swift?

Tags: swift3, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I want to match the size of "yellow_noise.png" to the size of the "pickedImage" from the UIImagePickerController. What should I do?

```
    originalImageView.image = pickedImage
    overayImageView.image = UIImage(named:"yellow_noise.png")
```

[image]

Comment: For example 1st image is larger than other, so do you want to scale up smaller one to larger, or do you want to scale down larger one to smaller, or do you want to crop larger one and keep middle portion with similar size as smaller image?

Comment: @MehulThakkar I want to fit a large image ("overlayImage.image") to a small image ("pickedImage") without cutting it.

Comment: So.. you want to scale down larger(overlay image) to size of smaller image.. right?

Comment: Go to this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/34599236/2160144, create extension similar to that, now call this method as, `overayImageView.scaleImage(toSize: originalImageView.size)`

Comment: @MehulThakkar Thank you. But It's not working... I added result of picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could do something like this:

```
let overlayImageView = UIImageView(frame: originalImageView.frame)
overlayImageView.image = UIImage(named:"yellow_noise.png")
```

Comment: Thank you. But the size and position of overayimage do not match exactly.