# tvOS adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused crops image collection view cell

Tags: uiimage, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, tvos

When you use `.imageView.adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused` you get your image scaled, you get it bigger on focus. The image goes beyond it's bounds. That means that you can't see full image - it's coped on all sides.

You have:

[image]

You want:

[image]

Comment: I am facing same issue in tvOS app. if image size is not 16:9 ratio then focus image is not showing properly and image croped.

Comment: Can you solve it this problem?

Comment: @vipulk617 Please read my answer.

Comment: @vipulk617   [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37252934/3695647)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it work from the box, you need to remember to reserve Focused/Safe zone size (from documentation) when you create your image.

In my case I have my images from server and I can't edit them.
What worked for me - it's to redraw image right before setting:

```
    UIImage *oldImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"example"];
    CGFloat width = cell.imageView.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat height = cell.imageView.frame.size.height;
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
    CGRect newRect = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height));
    CGImageRef imageRef = oldImage.CGImage;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0);
    CGContextRef resizeContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(resizeContext, kCGInterpolationHigh);
    CGAffineTransform flipVertical = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, newSize.height);

    CGContextConcatCTM(resizeContext, flipVertical);
    CGContextDrawImage(resizeContext, newRect, imageRef);

    CGImageRef newImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(resizeContext);
    UIImage *newImageResized = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef];

    CGImageRelease(newImageRef);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        cell.imageView.image = newImageResized;
    });
```

It's nor necessary to redraw in this way, but the point is you need to draw your `UIImage` again in order to have your image displayed properly.

Code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7775470/3695647).

Comment: When do you re-draw them? If you're applying this code dynamically on focus, isn't there a performance issue?